# running lynx through php

Tags: php, lynx

I have a list of URLs in a text file, one on each line.  I'd like to run each of them through lynx to get a dump of tag-less text by using the following method:

```
foreach ($result as $url) {
//lynx each url and append to output file
exec("lynx -dump 'http://mysite.co.uk/?p=12' >> output.txt");
$i++;
}
```

(I've tried shell-exec too) but it won't work - I either get an empty output file or the message: 'lynx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  I'm running it through cygwin, and lynx works normally that way.

Questions:

1. should it be possible this way?
2. could it instead be done through cygwin console by 'including' text file and looping through each URL?
3. would you recommend a different way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

DM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You tell us that you do this in cygwin so I would use a script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
for result in `cat url.txt`
do
   (echo;echo "$result";echo;echo )>>output.txt
   lynx -dump $result >>output.txt
done
```

Where url.txt is your file with URLs.